# Method overriding with Exception handling - Compiler's role in runtime Polymorphism?

Tags: java, exception, compiler-construction, overriding, checked

Please consider this snippet demonstrating method overriding with exception handling.
I know that the subclass overridden method cannot declare a broader exception compared to the superclass method.
I was just wondering as to why this rule was made?

My understanding...

Let's assume, it was **valid** for the subclass method to declare a broader exception like this -

```
class Parent
{
  public void disp() throws IOException
  {
    System.out.println("Parent disp()");
  }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
  public void disp() throws Exception //widening
  {
    System.out.println("Child disp()");
  }
}
```

And using Polymorphism, when the method is called with a Parent reference like this.

```
Parent p = new Child();
p.disp();
```

In this case, I believe the compiler will not look at the Child class overridden method, but based on the reference type (Here it is "Parent"), it would look at the Parent class disp() method. And as per the signature of that method (Precisely, throws IOException), it would have compelled the programmer to handle the exception when the call is made, like this.

```
try
{
  p.disp();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
  //handling code
}
```

Now comes the problem, during runtime, the method call will obviously get binded with the Child class overridden disp() method. But this method had declared a broader exception in its signature, which unfortunately cannot be handled by the catch block because catch block can handle all subtypes of exceptions of the parameter type specified (Here it is IOException) but not the supertypes.

Clearly, Exception type can't handled by IOException.
And hence the rule that overridden method in the subclass cannot declare a broader exception. But can declare narrow exception types.

Since, the compiler will consider the Parent class method which has a broader exception declared compared to Child class overridden method, the catch block can easily handle any subtype of the exception declared in the overridden method.

Please acknowledge if my understanding is right so far.

If it's right, then can the following be concluded:

In the case of method overriding,

1. During compile time, the compiler will consider the method based on the reference type and not based on the type of the instance. So, it's Parent method ofcourse by abiding the rules of method overriding.
2. But during run-time, the JVM will decide the method to be invoked based on the instance type.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. What is your question exactly?

Comment: Thanks, @Sweeper. The question was only to validate my understanding. Thanks again.

Comment: (1).It isn't valid. (2). The compiler will treat `p` as the type it was declared as, namely `Parent`, and (3) force the programmer to handle `IOException`. whereas the actual method that is called at runttime can by your rules actually throw `Exception`, which the compiler hasn't forced to be handled. Which is exactly why it isn't valid. Your question?